# Mixing jQuery and JavaScript too much?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this valid jQuery? Or have I mixed it up with regular JavaScript too much? In any case it is not working (I would expect it to print "testing" between the appropriate  tags):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var testing = "testing";
  testIt=function() {
    $('#cont').html(testing);
  }
</script>
```

to be invoked when:

```
<input TYPE="button" NAME="button4" Value="Write" onClick="testIt()">
```

obviously there is a:

```
<div id="cont"> </div>
```

in the html.

Comment: jQuery _is_ JavaScript! I wouldn't worry about mixing the two ;-)

Comment: You accepted the answer but we still don't know what's wrong with your  code ?

Comment: Ahh, sorry (first time), basically I had forgotten to include the jquery library, I'm a moron. Quickly learning the need to create a full, minimal example for each and every problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not "mixing jQuery and Javascript" too much. jQuery **is** Javascript. You won't ever have to worry about mixing them.

I can't reproduce your problem. Your code seems to be working fine. [See it in this demo](http://jsbin.com/inedis/edit#html,live).

That said, I think you should use a method that is more idiomatic to jQuery instead of mixing Javascript with the markup.

I would recommend changing the `NAME` attribute

```
NAME="button4"
```

to an `id` attribute:

```
id="button4
```

and using this jQuery:

```
var testing = "testing"; 
$("#button4").click(function(){
  $("#cont").html(testing); 
});
```

Comment: Any idea why this might not be working? If I put alert("Hello World!"); inside the function it works just fine

Comment: @JimBo I don't know, maybe you could have referenced a name that doesn't exist (e.g. the id of the div is `content` but you are trying to reference `cont`)

Comment: Traced the problem back to something totally unrelated, thanks for your help, esp. with the example (and thanks everyone else who showed me the proper way to do it).

Answer (score 2):

1. JQuery is a javascript library
2. Your code works properly. The only mistake I could think about is that you didn't include JQuery in your html file.

Comment: Exactly that, I had included a load of libraries and stupidly forgot jquery, that explained why the alert() was working but not the .html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, I would recommend using the `click` handler instead of creating a global variable `testIt`. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var testing = "testing";
    $("input[name='button4']").click(function() {
        $('#cont').html(testing);
    });
</script>
```

That provides a nicer separation between your behaviour (javascript) and your content/markup (html).

Technically no, there's no such thing as mixing too much jQuery and javascript (as jQuery is javascript). Since jQuery is an abstraction of a lot of the messy stuff that the DOM does, it would make sense to leverage it where you can rather than writing pure javascript. Writing in as much jQuery as possible also has the benefit that you can worry less about cross-browser differences.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery (which is a framework written in/ for JS) anyway, do it in a proper way to improve readability:

```
var testing = "testing";
$("button[name=button4]").click(function () {
    $("#cont").html(testing);
});
```

Either put this after the button, or put the code between `$(function () {` and `});`. jQuery has an excellent documentation which is available at http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Does your script tag appear before the `input` element in the page?  If not, that's the problem (or at least one of them).

Alternatively check to make sure there aren't any other javascript errors on the page by checking the console in any of the various JS debuggers.

P.S. JQuery is Javascript, more specifically it's a library of helper code written in Javascript to make working with the browser more convenient.